¿por que arroja NULL?
Utilizo este código para conseguir el último registro para luego imprimirlo en un input pero el resultado me retorna null
$stmt = pg_prepare($connect, "MaxNroHistoria", "SELECT max(nrohistoria) as MaxNroHistoria FROM public.pacientes");

// Ejecutar la consulta
$result = pg_execute($connect, "MaxNroHistoria", array());
if ($result) {
    $row = pg_fetch_assoc($result);
    if ($row && !is_null($row['MaxNroHistoria'])) {
        $maxNroHistoria = $row['MaxNroHistoria'];
        echo "<table align='center'>
          <tr>
            <td class='sr'>Ultimo Nro de Historia:<input type='text' readonly='t' value='<?php echo $maxNroHistoria;?>' name='nrohistoria' size='10' maxlength='10' align='right'class='color1'/></td></tr>
        </table>";
     } else {
         echo "No se encontraron registros o el máximo número de historia es NULL.";
     }
} else {
    echo "Error al ejecutar la consulta: " . pg_last_error($connect);
}


Hola Alejandro ¿Que es lo que retorna null? ¿Acaso haces una llamada a este código desde otro lado? PD: Si queres que aparezca el valor en el input deberías hacerlo así: value='$maxNroHistoria' (el código PHP está de más)

No se mucho de postgre, pero, estás preparando la consulta, y luego ejecutandola, sin un control de errores de por medio. Deberías añadir un bloque try-catch, para obtener cualquier impedimento, y no esperar hasta el primer IF. Si la preparación falla, o la ejecución falla, no sabrás si retornaron null, por que el recurso podría ser válido aún.

No analice bien a detalle lo que quieres o como se originan tus resultados y peticiones pero si requieres que la consulta arroje alguna resultado y no null puedes alterar la consulta MySQL para que ello asi
$stmt = pg_prepare($connect, "MaxNroHistoria", 
"( SELECT max(nrohistoria) as MaxNroHistoria FROM public.pacientes )
      UNION #Peminte regrear un VALOR en lugar de un NULL...
 (SELECT 0) LIMIT 1; # Regresa "0"
");

También recuerda que aquí puedes estar recibiendo un '' = null pero no lo valida como null
if ($row && !is_null($row['MaxNroHistoria']))

También intenta ponerlo así...
if ($row && !is_null($row['MaxNroHistoria']) or $row['MaxNroHistoria'] !== '')



No es MySQL, es PostgreSQL. Además, OP preguntó por qué retorna null, no ha dicho quiero forzar a que el resultado no sea null.

bueno he seguido sus sugerencias. Ahora aparece este mensaje: array(1) { ["maxnrohistoria"]=> string(2) "22" } ese 22 es el ultimo registro de la tabla.
